# Limit button use to once prior to refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a button that only executes once. However, I seem to have an issue getting this to work.

My button adds parameters to a URL based on what is selected prior to clicking the 'lg-circ' button. You won't see the Logo's in my code. Thanks in advance.

```
    $('.lg-circ').on('click', function(){
  var executed = false;
  return function() {
    if (!executed) {
        executed = true;

    if ($('.semi-circle-1').hasClass('active') === true) {
      var type = 'John'
      URL = URL + type;
      console.log(URL)
  } else {
    var type = 'Sally'
    URL = URL + type;
  };

  if ($('.logo1').hasClass('active') === true) {
    var logo1 = '&source_list[]=Argos'
    URL = URL + logo1
  } else {
    var logo1 = ''
    URL = URL + logo1
  };

  if ($('.logo2').hasClass('active') === true) {
    var logo1 = '&source_list[]=Tesco'
    URL = URL + logo1
  } else {
    var logo1 = ''
    URL = URL + logo1
  };

  if ($('.logo10').hasClass('active') === true) {
    var logo1 = '&source_list[]=Argos'
    URL = URL + logo1
  } else {
    var logo1 = ''
    URL = URL + logo1
  };
  if ($('.logo2').hasClass('active') === true) {
    var logo1 = '&source_list[]=Tesco'
    URL = URL + logo1
  } else {
    var logo1 = ''
    URL = URL + logo1
  };
  console.log(URL)
  $('.clickysection').addClass('activated')
  $('.dead').detach();
  $.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zoomooz/1.1.6/jquery.zoomooz.js");
  }}});
```

Comment: Change `on()` to `one()`. Also note that this code needs to be DRY'd up as there's a lot of repetition which can be avoided

Comment: Rory you are a legend.

Comment: You are returning a function in the callback and it wont get executed.